# JPA update list of one to many relationship

Tags: hibernate, jpa, merge, entitymanager

I have a Question entity with a list of another entity called Alternatives like this:

```
public class Question {
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "question", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<Alternative> alternativeList;
}

public class Alternative implements Serializable {
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "questionId", nullable = false)
    @JsonBackReference
    private Question question;

}
```

Then I wanted to update an exiting Question entry with a new set of Alternative list. For this I'm calling merge method of my JpaDao element with the new Question object:

```
@Repository
public class JpaQuestionDao implements QuestionDao {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Transactional
    public Question update(Question question) {
        return em.merge(question);
    }
}
```

However, this is in fact merging the two lists: the one already in database and the new provided one. I haven't had any problem with such method when I have non-list objects, that's why I kept using merge method.

Is there an alternative method to not merge but only update a list?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Retrieve the question object first using EntityManager.find(). Question object will become managed as a result. Since alternativeList is lazily loaded, you have to invoke a method on the collections object to fetch it and make it managed as well. Any updates to the Question object and to the list will be automatically sent to the DB.

```
@Transactional
public Question update(Question question) {
    Question q = em.find(Question.class, question.getId());
    q.setAlternativeList(null);
    q.setAlternativeList(question.getAlternativeList());
    ...

    return q;
}
```

Alternatively, you can try using orphanRemoval=true on your @OneToMany collection

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "question", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
@JsonManagedReference
private List<Alternative> alternativeList;
```

Comment: Still same problem with this :( I set the altList like this         q.setAlternativeList(question.getAlternativeList());

Comment: Hmm, what exactly do you want to do with the list? I mean what do you expect with your list contents when it gets to the DB?

Comment: For example, I have item 1, 2 and 3 in DB. Then I wanted to call update method passing a new Question object in new Alternative list, let's suppose 1,2 and 5 (instead of 3). Instead of this, I'm getting an Alternative list with 1, 2, 3, 1, 2 and 5.

Comment: Try the updated code. I first removed the list by setting it to null, then update the list.

Alternatively, you can try the orphanRemoval property in @OneToMany annotation.

Comment: @Ish _"Any updates to the Question object and to the list will be automatically sent to the DB."_ Wrong, `Question` is the inverse side of the association. `orphanRemoval` will work though (`question` is not nullable in the `Alternative` so I assume it's the OP's intention to delete unused `Alternative`s).

Comment: @Ish, I took your suggestion regarding the orphanRemove and fortunately this is what was missing in my one to many relation.. No need to set null to lists and this kind of things, only setting orphan remove works with original code. Thanks for your help!

Comment: `orphanRemoval` only works with `cascade = ALL` in my case. `cascade = MERGE` doesn't delete any child.