# List within an entity does not refresh

Tags: java, jpa, netbeans

I'm using JPA and I have an entity that has relation (one to many), the entity is called "Part" which contains a list of "ProcessEstimate" called processes, but when I insert into the database a new "ProcessEstimate", the list inside "Part" It is not updated, as it still shows me the list of "ProcessEstimate" that I had before inserting.

How can I make the list update without avoiding the cache?

This is my Part entity:

```
@Entity
public class Part implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

private String name;
private int quantity;                 

private String notes;
private boolean materialProvided;

@ManyToOne
private Project project;
@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private DataFile dataFile;

private String material;   

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "part", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<ProcessEstimate> processes;

public Part(){        
    processes = new LinkedList<>();
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 0;
    hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
    if (!(object instanceof Part)) {
        return false;
    }
    Part other = (Part) object;
    return !((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id)));
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return String.valueOf(id);
}


/**
 * @return the quantity
 */
public int getQuantity() {
    return quantity;
}

/**
 * @param quantity the quantity to set
 */
public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
    this.quantity = quantity;
}

/**
 * @return the notes
 */
public String getNotes() {
    return notes;
}

/**
 * @param notes the notes to set
 */
public void setNotes(String notes) {
    this.notes = notes;
}

/**
 * @return the materialProvided
 */
public boolean isMaterialProvided() {
    return materialProvided;
}

/**
 * @param materialProvided the materialProvided to set
 */
public void setMaterialProvided(boolean materialProvided) {
    this.materialProvided = materialProvided;
}

/**
 * @return the dataFile
 */
public DataFile getDataFile() {
    return dataFile;
}

/**
 * @param dataFile the dataFile to set
 */
public void setDataFile(DataFile dataFile) {
    this.dataFile = dataFile;
}


/**
 * @return the name
 */
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

/**
 * @param name the name to set
 */
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}       

/**
 * @return the project
 */
public Project getProject() {
    return project;
}

/**
 * @param project the project to set
 */
public void setProject(Project project) {
    this.project = project;
}            

/**
 * @return the processes
 */
public List<ProcessEstimate> getProcesses() {
    return processes;
}

/**
 * @param processes the processes to set
 */
public void setProcesses(List<ProcessEstimate> processes) {
    this.processes = processes;
}

/**
 * @return the material
 */
public String getMaterial() {
    return material;
}

/**
 * @param material the material to set
 */
public void setMaterial(String material) {
    this.material = material;
}

}
```

This is my ProcessEstimate entity:

```
@Entity
public class ProcessEstimate implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@ManyToOne
private Part part;

@OneToOne
private Process process;

private String typeTime;

@Column(name = "PROCESS_TIME")
private float time;

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 0;
    hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
    if (!(object instanceof ProcessEstimate)) {
        return false;
    }
    ProcessEstimate other = (ProcessEstimate) object;
    return !((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id)));
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return String.valueOf(id);
}

/**
 * @return the part
 */
public Part getPart() {
    return part;
}

/**
 * @param part the part to set
 */
public void setPart(Part part) {
    this.part = part;
}

/**
 * @return the process
 */
public Process getProcess() {
    return process;
}

/**
 * @param process the process to set
 */
public void setProcess(Process process) {
    this.process = process;
}

/**
 * @return the time
 */
public float getTime() {
    return time;
}

/**
 * @param time the time to set
 */
public void setTime(float time) {
    this.time = time;
}

/**
 * @return the typeTime
 */
public String getTypeTime() {
    return typeTime;
}

/**
 * @param typeTime the typeTime to set
 */
public void setTypeTime(String typeTime) {
    this.typeTime = typeTime;
}

}
```

Sorry my english is bad.

Comment: A lot of people think that JPA is magic, it is not, the behavior is well defined, but you have to know the rules to predict what will happen. When you persist an entity with a OneToMany child relation the collection of children will never be changed (the objects in the list may get an Id if they are new). What did you expect would happen after you persisted the parent (the the list through cascade) ?

Comment: La Lista de <ProcessEstimate> refrescado en la entidad Parte. Sólo quiero algo como esto: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32980044/jpa-update-list-of-one-to-many-relationship but I'm using EclipseLinks